# UnsupportedClassVersionError in Spring tool suite-4 version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, version

I am trying to run my spring project but encountering this error:

```
`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServlet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0 (unable to load class [jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet]) (unable to load class [org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean]) (unable to load class [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet]) (unable to load class [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet])`
```

I have done the following chnages:

**1. Went to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries and edit the execution environment to java se-17**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTWj3.png)

**2. Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> 17**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3TMe.png)

**I have installed java 17 version in laptop.**

Still it shows the same error. I am newbie in this, Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: what build tool do you use like maven or gradle ?

Comment: I have used maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conversion table from class version to jdk version**

Here is the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

- 65 = jdk21
- 61 = jdk17

**Problem**

Error indicates you try to load a class (servlet) with jdk17 that is compiled with jdk21.

We need more information(pom.xml) to make a complete diagnose but you probably used latest version of spring/spring boot requiring jdk21.

I advise not use jdk17 for beginners. [Here](https://jakarta.ee/blogs/javax-jakartaee-namespace-ecosystem-progress/) is more information about breaking changes, subject a little complex to apprehend.

To sum up, all stack including spring mvc, spring boot, tomcat, jdk, eclipse... has been recompiled/reworked to take these breaking changes into account.

**Solution without need to fully understand**

So just update all your libraries to last version, and use latest version of jdk21 in your Eclipse. Do not forget to take also one of the latest version of Eclipse compatible with jdk21.

It is easier than try to figure out which version of spring is compatible with which eclipse or which tomcat or whatever tool in your stack.